# Laravel morphTo relation

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to get my subscription pivot table to work but I keep getting this error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'subscription_type' in 'field list' (SQL: update `topic` set `updated_at` = 2016-10-02 18:06:49, `subscription_type` = App\Square\Users\User, `subscription_id` = 1 where `id` = 1)'
```

So I've got 3 tables:

```
User
Subscription
Topic
```

A user can subscribe to a topic. This is how the Subscription table looks like:

```
Schema::create('subscription', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->index();
    $table->integer('subscription_id');
    $table->string('subscription_type');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->unique(['user_id', 'subscription_id', 'subscription_type']);
});
```

My relation in the `User` model:

```
public function subscriptions()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Subscription::class, 'subscription');
}
```

So when I try this in `php artisan tinker`:

```
App\Square\Users\User::first()->subscriptions()->save(App\Square\Topics\Topic::first());
```

I receive the error! What am I doing wrong? (I need this polymorphic table because I've to use it for some more things)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you need to use $table->morphs('subscription');

This will create the two columns for id and type automatically and enforce the relationship.

I was searching for an answer to a morph related question and stumbled upon your unanswered one. It's a really really late response, but hopefully a solution.